# Need help using `vsf-customer` cookie in vsf2 extended with Nuxt3

Tags: magento, cookies, server-side-rendering, nuxt3, vue-storefront

I am building an app in `vsf2` using `Nuxt 3` and `magento2` integration. While trying to implement `sinup` and `signin`, I used following `methods` provided by the `magento sdk`:

`createCustomer`
`customer`
`generateCustomerToken`
`revokeCustomerToken`

initially, I wanted to use `vsf-customer` to store `cookies` as recommended in the documentation but I couldn't find a way to implement it, all I know is that I have to register `cookies` in the `middleware` configurations. So, I used `localStorage` and all works fine but when I applied `route guards` using route `middleware` from `nuxt`, the page throws me `500` and only upon refreshing the page it redirects me to the `login` screen. Below is my code and some screenshots.

router middleware:
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dt7r.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAaBk.png)

```
import { defineNuxtRouteMiddleware, navigateTo } from 'nuxt/app';

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  let router = useRouter();
  let userToken = localStorage.getItem('customerToken');
  console.log(userToken, ' inside local storage');
  if (userToken == null) {
    return router.push('/login');
  }
});
```

Token Generator:

```
type generateCustomerTokenType = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  };

  const generateCustomerToken = async (tokenObj: generateCustomerTokenType) => {
    const { data } = await useAsyncData(() => useSdk().magento.generateCustomerToken(tokenObj));
    console.log('Token data: ', data.value?.data?.generateCustomerToken?.token);
    return data;
  };
```

Login Logic:

```
const createLoginObj = () => ({
  email: email.value,
  password: password.value
})

type loginObjType = {
  email: string,
  password: string
}

const login = async () => {
  const loginObj: loginObjType = createLoginObj();
  try {
      const tokenData = await generateCustomerToken(loginObj);
      if (!tokenData.value?.errors) {
        const token: any = tokenData.value?.data?.generateCustomerToken?.token;
        localStorage.setItem('customerToken', token);
        await fetchCustomer();
        isLoading.value = false;
        router.push('/my-account');
      } else throw new Error(tokenData.value.errors[0].message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error occured: ", error);
      errorMsg.value = error as string;
      isLoading.value = false;
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
};
```